# HEVC decoding with VA-API is not recognizing my device

Tags: encoding, video-streaming, hevc, vaapi

I'm using [libva](https://github.com/intel/libva) to decode HEVC binary file. The following to code to decode a single HEVC encoded frame.

```
int main() {
   int drm_fd = open("/dev/dri/card0", O_RDWR); // OK
   VADisplay display = vaGetDisplayDRM(drm_fd); // OK
   int major, minor;
   vaInitialize(display, &major, &minor);       // runtime-error: Error code 0xffffffff: 
   // more code 
   return 0; 
}
```

The error thrown is not descriptive unfortunately. `Error code 0xffffffff: unknown libva error`

I get same result if I use `/dev/dri/render128` as well.

`vainfo` looks healthy

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.20.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_20
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.20 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 23.2.1-1+build1 for AMD Radeon Pro WX 3200 Series (polaris12, LLVM 16.0.6, DRM 3.54, Debian-12-amd64)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

I can see that `ffmpeg` + `vaapi` works fine too, this command runs fine

```
$ ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -vaapi_device /dev/dri/card0  -f hevc -i inputencodedsingleframe out.png
```

Some additional info on my setup

```
$ drm_info -j | jq 'with_entries(.value |= .driver.desc)'
{
  "/dev/dri/card0": "AMD GPU"
}

$ lspci | grep VGA
61:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3200] (rev 10)
```

I am starting to believe that VA-api doesn't work with AMD graphic cards but the fact that `vainfo` and `ffmpeg` works fine, tell me that might be something else. This code works fine in another linux machine so I don't know what can be different. Any pointers will be appreciated.